# Could(parallelism) accuracy. Other helping verbs possible?(present tense)

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, parallelism

As an ESL, one cannot be completely accurate in their ''parallelism'' sometimes. Like this one:

> "**If** I can't tolerate simple criticisms or much worse even, I still **couldn't** regard myself as a changed person then, I'm still the same person *I was* before, obviously. Tolerance **could** be the key, which **could** help me to reach my goal. And once I **am** finally at the top, it **could** be a rather less stressful place as mediocre individuals **could** already be weeded out.

The main modal verb is **could**, but sometimes it doesn't look correct(I think) particularly in the *very last sentence.* Is this correct to you?

Comment: **Or more worse** is wrong, and the passage as a whole is awkward, but I see no problem with the use of **could** from a syntactic point of view.

Comment: **much worse** how about that?

Comment: Are you using this as a method of proofreading your passage? ;) I could expand on what I had said, but will stop there . . .

Comment: Just partially, I'm just an ESL and I wanted to learn as much as I can because I wanted to be proficient. Please expand the answer then.

Comment: Where is it Jason? :)

Comment: What I had meant to say was that I've already expressed my essential thoughts with regard to **could** (and also commented on some unrelated things). "Fixing" the rest of the passage would be considered proofreading, and that is discouraged. If you have another concern about something specific, I would ask a different question that focuses on it.